# Display multiple series on Grafana with wildcards

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Can you display multiple series on Grafana without having to create one query per line?

For example, instead of creating two queries like this:

```
sum(up{app="app-1"})
sum(up{app="app-2"})
```

Can you do something like this to display two lines on a graph?

```
sum(up{app="app-*"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You can use regular expressions to select time series only for apps matching a certain pattern (in this case starting with `app-`). Then use the `by` clause to take the sum by the `app` label:

```
sum(up{app=~"app-.*"}) by (app)
```

---

*A related example with a graph:*

[image: example]

```
sum(http_server_requests_seconds_count{uri=~"/membership/.*"}) by (uri)
```